# How to know if locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() has already been asked

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios11

When requesting user's iOS location permissions, how could I know if `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` has already been asked to the user?

In case the user had `.AuthorizedWhenInUse` status and the request for always authorization has been denied, the always-auth prompt for the next request won't be shown so I won't get any callback of this request launch.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can do this by using UserDefaults or using the authorization status

Comment: This is for an app update. If in a previous app version location permissions were asked and user selected "when in use", I don't know now if "always" permission was already asked...

Answer (score 2):

You need to check `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()` and only request authorization if the value is `.notDetermined`, since this is the only case when the authorization prompt will actually be shown.

Comment: This is for an app update. If in a previous app version location permissions were asked and user selected "when in use", I don't know now if "always" permission was already asked...

Comment: Highest voted answer, hence this comment: this is not (no longer?) correct for iOS 13 and up. You can first ask for "when-in-use", then ask again to 'upgrade' to "always". If the user then changes the setting back to "when-in-use" via settings or the system dialog, you're out of luck and will not be able to ask again.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of brainstorming this issue, I've found a solution.

1. Check authorization status each time the app starts, or when the app enters the foreground after the user views the Settings app.
2. If status is `notDetermined`, request `authorizedWhenInUse`. You can't jump straight to `authorizedAlways`.
3. If status is `authorizedWhenInUse`, request `authorizedAlways`.

**The catch**, as you know, is when the user goes from `notDetermined` to `notDetermined`, i.e. doesn't change their settings. We need to be able to see what the status was *before* they were prompted.

This is actually easy, just save the value of `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()` in a property called `previousAuthStatus`.

```
private var previousAuthStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
```

When the application enters the foreground, check the authorization state with that previous state.

## Full code

**Don't miss the last bit where `previousAuthStatus` is set**

```
func checkStatus(_ status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    switch status {

    case .notDetermined:

        // request "When in use"
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    case .authorizedWhenInUse:

        // already tried requesting "Always"?
        guard previousAuthStatus != .authorizedWhenInUse else {
            <#notify the user...#>
            break
        }

        // otherwise, request "Always"
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    case .authorizedAlways:

        // start updating location
        <#dismiss any warning you may have displayed#>
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    case .denied:

        <#notify the user...#>

    case .restricted:

        <#notify the user...#>

    @unknown default:

        break
    }

    // save status for next check
    previousAuthStatus = status
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [Authorization status](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clauthorizationstatus) and compare if it's `notDetermined` it has not been asked, else - it's been asked.

Comment: This is for an app update. If in a previous app version location permissions were asked and user selected "when in use", I don't know now if "always" permission was already asked...

Answer (score 1):

You can know by using `authorizationStatus()` like this.

```
if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
    print("Not Determined")
}
else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .restricted {
     print("Restricted")
}
else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied {
     print("Denied")
}
else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {
    print("Always Authorized")
}
else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
    print("Authorized When Require")
}
```

If the Dialog appear for 1st time it returns `.notDetermined` status and if you respond to dialog than it returns status based on your selection like if you allow to access your location always that it returns `.authorizedAlways`.

Comment: This is for an app update. If in a previous app version location permissions were asked and user selected "when in use", I don't know now if "always" permission was already asked...

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem. This is not a problem for app updates (where you did not store authStatus in UserDefaults in previous version) only. It is also a problem if a user decides to uninstall and reinstall the app (user defaults are removed), or user manually change the status from 'Always' to 'When in Use' (no way of knowing that it was changed to 'When in Use' or if it was that status all along).

Btw: the user manually changing the authorisation is actually very common, because iOS now brings up an alert every once in a while "AppName has been using your location in the background... do you want to continue allowing this" (or something like that don't remember exactly). Lots of my users choose 'No' in that alert, resulting in the 'Always' location access being changed to 'When in Use' without the app getting a notification about that.

iOS however does remember if `requestAlwaysAccess` was already asked before, no matter what. Even after an uninstall and reinstall of the app.

So, with lack of other options I'm now using this, which honestly, is not the most user friendly, but it does work and is user friendly 'enough' (for me at least).

In stead of requesting always authorisation, I simply bring up an alert, with one of the buttons pointing to the apps Settings page, where user can then manually change the setting. I did add a userdefault storing if the app showed this alert before. If it did, I won't show it again.

```
switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .restricted, .denied:
        // show an alert with one button opening settings (see below)                   
    case .authorizedAlways:
        // already have always permission, continue with your code
    case .notDetermined:
        // request whenInUse authorisation (you can request always authorisation here too, but iOS won't show 'always' as a choice the first time)
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        guard !UserDefaults.showedNoAlwaysAuthorisationAlert else {
            return
        }
        UserDefaults.showedNoAlwaysAuthorisationAlert = true
        // show the alert with "no thanks" and "settings" button
        // button action:
        if 'settingsButtonTapped', let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
             UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: nil)
        }
}
```